# How remove com.synconset.imagepicker 2.1.8 "ImagePicker"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

`imagepicker` is causing problems and need to delete.

How to I delete image picker? It is not coming up as plugin, it is coming up as:

```
                 com.synconset.imagepicker 2.1.8 "ImagePicker"
                   cordova-plugin-camera 3.0.0 "Camera"
                   cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
                 cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
                  cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

run: `cordova plugin remove com.synconset.imagepicker`

Comment: You should add a description to your answer so it's easy for other people to understand.